# App or program for recording people's circle and connection?

Tags: google-apps

Is there any android app or win PC program to make notes or a diagram about people's circle and connection? Such as, who likes whom, dislikes, hates, rival, competes, close friends, buddy, having a strong small cycle, something like that? I would like to call it a connection or social diplomacy management app. Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like a very good question (+1), but I think that might have translated "cycle" wrongly (***maybe*** "circle"? i.e "social circle" - see also [social group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_group)). Good luck :-)

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed it is circle. I fix it.

Comment: "Social circle" is probably better English, but that is clear enough. Good luck. I hope that you get an answer :-)